# Electron event fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, electron

I have one page, that load new elements via jquery. I have page that have event listener like

```
ipcRenderer.send('getlist');
ipcRenderer.once('return:list', function (e, l, wn) {
    console.log('a');
    for(let i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
        $('.a').append('<div>'+l[i]+wn[i]'</div>');
    }
    $('.a').append('<div>End</div>');
});
```

Code that send data to page:

```
ipcMain.on('getlist', function (e) {
    wn = [];
    cfg['a'].forEach(s => {
        wn.push(yaml.readSync('charcfg.yaml')['name']);
    });
    mainWindow.webContents.send('return:list', cfg['a'], wn);
});
```

And it's works perfectly until I load another page, and again load this page.
This event fires multiple times. Each time I come back to this page, more times it goes.

I tried to use

```
ipcRenderer.once('someevent', function(e, l){...});
```

It's works only ONE TIME. On third reload it's starts do listener multiple times again.

Code with this script loads with page!

Sorry for my english.[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ik38.png)

Function that loads page via jquery:

```
const htmlContent = $('.content');
function setContent(s) {
    $('.content').animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 200, function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            htmlContent.load(s + '.html');
            $('.content').animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 200);
        }, 100);
    });
}
```

Comment: What exactly is happening in your handlers that happens multiple times? More specific context would be helpful.

Comment: It's dynamically adds content on page, using data that receives from event

Comment: It'd be better if you edit your post so I can see it formatted, easier to interpret. But What exactly is happening multiple times? The append or the whole handler?

Comment: Okay, I edited my post. Multiple times appends text that recieves from event.

Comment: So is there a list involved like your initial comment or is it just a static append?

Comment: List. There foreach() to add all elements that variable l contains.

Comment: So that should be what your edit shows, it's very different. I would check your main side of the ipc. I suspect you're not resetting the list that you're sending, so it just grows every time.

Comment: No, this list resetting and sending only needed data. There only problem with listener that calls multiple times.

Comment: If you could post your full listener and maybe some example of what it's showing or a console.log it'd be much easier to understand what you're saying.

Comment: I made an edit.

Comment: So it prints 'a' multiple times in the renderer?

Comment: Yes, I added output in the end of post. Each time i open and close this window new 'a' adds. it's like 5,6,7,8 'a'.

Comment: Is that renderer code only being run once per page or is it in some other function that can be run multiple times?

Comment: Also, maybe try using ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners on page unload, might help I don't know.

Comment: That code runs each time i load document to page with this code. I load html to another div via jquery

Comment: I tried to use removeAllListener but it's same as i do .once()

Comment: So wait, is this renderer code not in it's own page loaded by electron but in something that you load with jquery?

Comment: Yes, this is only one page. I load some.html with this code each time via jquery and don't reload it. Script on some.html everytime do thing as i load page.

Comment: So theres page page1.html that loads page2.html (which contains this code) via jquery, or page1.html itself has this code in it?

Comment: Yes, first thing. page1.html that loads page2.html (which contains this code)

Comment: So how are you loading that inner page?

Comment: Added to post at the end

Comment: Did you try using removeAllListeners at the beginning of that setContent function?

Comment: No, i'll do that tomorrow. Thanks for your support. I will write here tomorrow, no matter it works or not. Good night

Comment: With a clear head after sleep, I figured out the problem.
Actually there was TWO listeners that go twice.

It's ipcRenderer.on(replaced to .once)
and jqury.on('click) that was binded to button that loads page.
Fixed this with jquery.unbind().on('click').

Comment: I'm facing the same problem but in different scenario.If anybody could help. [Ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906065/electron-js-event-is-firing-multiple-times?noredirect=1#comment113006699_63906065)

Answer (score 4):

Actually there was TWO listeners that go twice.

It's `ipcRenderer.on` (replaced to `.once`) and `jquery.on('click')` that was bound to button that loads page. Fixed this with `jquery.unbind().on('click')`.

Thanks for your help, obermillerk.

Comment: Just wanted to add that in my case I've included `renderer.js` in my html manually and it was already getting included by `main.js` so that's why it fired twice for me.