# Switching between Vue Router pages cause multiple event fire on VueJS mounted()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, vue-router, vue-cli

I am working on an [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org) project where I use Vue CLI project and the [Vue CLI Plugin Electron Builder](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/). Everything works great except a weird bug that I found recently.

Whenever I navigate between pages (Vue Router), the event I listen for from the component `mounted()` property becomes double. It's actually the `N+1` issue.

to describe the issue more clearly, I have two `Home.vue` and `HelloWorld.vue` components. From `Home.vue` component, I am sending an event to the `main` process whenever clicking a button and  listening the `event.reply()` from the same component `mounted()` property. It's completely as expected at this stage.

However, whenever I go to the `HelloWorld` page and switch back to the `Home` page again and when I click the button to send and receive the `event` from the `main` process, I don't only see a single `event` even though I click one time only but I see two `event` reply. If I switch between pages again, I'll see three `event` reply and so on like `N+1` issue.

For your convenience, I made a quick GIF that will show the issue clearly.

[image: sending and receiving event from the Electron main process]

`Home.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <button @click="send()">Home</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      cause: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.ipcRenderer.on("home:reply", event => console.log(event));
  },
  methods: {
    send() {
      window.ipcRenderer.send("home");
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

`main.js`

```js
ipcMain.on("home", event => {
  return event.reply("home:reply");
});
```

I don't have anything special on the Vue Router and it's just default scaffolding that comes with the Vue CLI. As you can see in the above code snippet, all I am doing is just sending an event when clicking a button and listening for the same event reply from the same component `mounted()` property.

I also found [a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891426/electron-event-fires-multiple-times) on Stack Overflow but couldn't figure it out myself. I have no clue what's wrong on my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unregister the event handler when the component is destroyed, otherwise you'll just keep registering the same event handler again and again each time the component is mounted.

```js
mounted() {
  window.ipcRenderer.on('home:reply', this.handleHomeReply)
},

destroyed() {
  window.ipcRenderer.off('home:reply', this.handleHomeReply)
},

methods: {
  handleHomeReply(event) {
    console.log(event)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is also why you should always use named functions for your event handlers, rather than the `(ev)=>{...}` style, even though the latter can be very tempting when the `...` bit is short and simple (as it is in the question).

Comment: Damn, that was it. Thanks man! I didn't find any document about the `ipcRenderer.off()` anywhere and never thought of it really ✌️